# How to get rid of post meta on pages but keep it on posts (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I am using the "Sight" theme by WP Shower to build http://www.dantiesmith-brown.com

I want to get rid of the meta info (author, time/date/etc..) on pages so that the only thing that displays on a PAGE (i.e. everything that is not the "news" tab, which is the blog)

is the name of the page, the line underneath it, and then the body copy underneath that. I would like the post meta stuff to appear on actual posts, but I want it removed from the pages.

How can I do this?

p.s. the WP Shower forum is not very helpful. I posted this same question several days ago and it hasn't even been uploaded to their forum yet..

Comment: May be better on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit `wp-content/thmemes/sight/page.php` and remove this part:

```
by <span class="post-author"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" title="Posts by <?php the_author(); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span> on <span class="post-date"><?php the_time(__('M j, Y')) ?></span> &bull; <span><?php the_time() ?></span>
```

Comment: @Roger if the answer solved your problem, it's good practice to click the accept button next to it so future visitors know it's been solved (it will also give Michal S. some deserved reputation).

Comment: Ok cool just did that I think? I assume it is the green check mark?